# Закрыть старую дочернюю MDI форму при открытии новой

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу чтобы в моей программе одновременно могла быть открытой только одна дочерняя форма MDI. Т.е. при открытии новой формы старая закрывалась, но я не нашёл как это можно реализовать. Написал следующий код в событии активации дочерней формы, но не знаю как удалить именно старую форму. Может кто-нибудь подсказать?

```
private void Main_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (f.IsMdiChild == true)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Открываю формы следующим образом по нажатию на кнопку:

```
Products form = new Products();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение проблемы, вдруг кому понадобится.
Нужно добавить следующий код перед созданием каждой дочерней формы

```
if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
    ActiveMdiChild.Close();
```